# Setting tab distance for selected text in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I was looking at an old template that I used in MS word and saw that some of the tab spacing was set to different distances. for example the tab was changed from .5" to about 4". Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight some text (or all your text).  Do a right-click and choose Paragraph.  Now, notice that at the bottom left there is a "Tabs..." button.  Click that.  There is a default tab spacing value at the top right -- probably 0.5.  You can change that.